# Wi-Fi connections are dropping

Tags: wireless

I'm having a problem with my [USB] Wi-Fi connection in Ubuntu 14.04.4, it keeps dropping after every few minutes and I then need to restart my laptop to connect again. My phone connects well to the network so it shouldn't be a network issue.

I typed `lshw -C network` and received the following:

```
root@ninas-Lenovo-U31-70:/home/nina# lshw -C network
*-network               
  description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 15
   serial: f0:76:1c:fc:09:28
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4404000-c4404fff memory:c4400000-c4403fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c4200000-c43fffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 8c:ae:4c:f8:3c:36
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.2.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.21 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

I also ran the following script

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

It returns the following information.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Mar 2016 17:15 BST +0100

Booted last: 30 Mar 2016 17:15 BST +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3828]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]

04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8192cu              69632  0 
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        49152  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              729088  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              540672  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
snd_soc_rt286          40960  0 
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_soc_core          200704  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_pcm               102400  7 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
ideapad_laptop         24576  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  36864  3 i915,ideapad_laptop,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.0.21  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:33127 (33.1 KB)  TX bytes:16663 (16.6 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SKY72199"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       784     1  1 17:15 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [SKY72199] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    BTWifi-X:        Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA WPA2 Enterprise
    BTHub5-238J:     Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA2
    SKYF5CEA:        Infra, , Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA2
    TALKTALK997CB1:  Infra, , Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
    TALKTALK-2B3F5A: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47 WPA WPA2
    BTWifi-with-FON: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70
    *SKY72199:       Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 81 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.21
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

Acquisition of admin privileges failed.

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Acquisition of admin privileges failed.

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Ziv Huang   
author:         Georgia     
srcversion:     730D20DBF46D54850A5E8F4
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     E2BFFC8F9C4C5753F88B5D5
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Ziv Huang   
author:         Georgia     
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     1ED716BB42196D4EBC16CBE
depends:        rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     F4CACC5FCAEBE7C22930A24
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     FBF6EA073A00B4F3836226E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7982686FBE8064A87E02753
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   28.195338] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   28.223553] rtl8192cu: MAC address: 
[   28.223555] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   28.223630] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   28.223665] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   28.226877] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   28.232078] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   28.248384] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   28.627747] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   29.519562] wlan0: authenticate with 
[   29.530232] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[   29.546920] wlan0: authenticated
[   29.549649] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[   29.570911] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   29.571740] wlan0: associated
[   29.571750] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Does anyone see what the problem is? Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: You have two wireless adapters. Which one are you asking about? The USB or internal?

Comment: the USB one (the other one doesn't seem to work)

Comment: It is easier to get the internal work. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: it's 14.04.4 (sorry, should have written that)

Comment: Can you please display the output of `grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) }'`

Comment: So do you want to get the USB dongle work better, or get the internal adapter work?

Comment: well ideally I would like to get the internal adapter work

Comment: grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) }' returned 54

Comment: [Internal wifi fix](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in/678244#678244) use the manual method as the dkms doesn't work on the 4.2 kernel.  The USB would benefit from [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/730604/300665)

Comment: How about `iwlist scan | grep SKY72199 | grep cipher`

Comment: interface doesn't support scanning

Comment: Have you tried the manual method from http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in/678244#678244 to get the internal wifi going

Comment: I've now installed the driver for my internal wifi adapter following the your instruction and it works, but very slowly. It was also very slow under Windows 10.  My laptop (Lenovo U31)is brandnew. It might be bad hardware.

Comment: After typing #sudo iwconfig wlan1 power off I now receive an acceptable connection. So the problem seems to be resolved, at least for now. Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Answer (score 0):

What I see, is that your usb device is being used as your wlan0 - meaning it is using your USB to connect to the Wi-Fi. In your comments you said it didn't work? Then please remove it and let us get the internal one working.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: wlan0
```

Let us restart your network, so it starts to use the internal one
`sudo service network-manager restart` or `systemctl restart network-manager`

Once you have a working connection we should start too troubleshoot, if you loose connection do:
`dmesg | tail`

Post those errors messages so we can see what whent wrong.

I gave you a command to display signal strength `grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) }'`, the output was 54%. Does it also happen when you sit closer to the Wi-Fi accesspoint?

Can you maybe also output:
`iwconfig`
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

**Network location**:
/etc/network/interfaces

If you edit anything here, a `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0` is needed to let the settings take effect.

Comment: I unplugged the external adapter but ubuntu doesn't use the internal adapter at all, I never had a connection using the internal adapter under ubuntu.

The signal strength goes up to almost 100 if I'm closer to the accesspoint.

Comment: @nnhg - take a look at this: [article link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: I've run the script from the article you posted the link to and posted the output into my original post.