# NetGear WNA3100M Wireless N300 not detecting any WiFi

Tags: wireless, 16.04, mate, netgear

On Ubuntu Mate 16.04. Did the steps in my own question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730601/safely-unmounting-a-netgear-wireless-usb-adapter/), but to no avail. The output of lsusb is exactly as in the former question, except the device is on Bus 002. At the time of the first question, I had Ubuntu Studio 15.10. Any ideas?

`sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update fixed this. All my wireless networks now appear, and i can connect to them. Seems the MATE team has been working on this issue.

Comment: do you know if the adapter works for Ubuntu 16.04 non-MATE?

Comment: @anon58192932, haven't tried it on another Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: mine arrives tomorrow! Will let you know. It's currently the cheapest wifi adapter on ebay and I need quite a few so took a bit of a gamble...